# How to automatically profile/time HttpWebRequests to a specific domain?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

My C# WebAPI talks to a backend database (Couchbase) using HTTP requests.  I have no control over the actual library that does the calls so I cannot simply time it from the code but I would like to save the timings of the calls to the database for SLA purposes.

Is there a way to intercept HTTP calls to a specific domain using Net.Tracing or something and save the timings of the calls?  Something similar to what the Network tab of Chrome provides.

Comment: Are you able to configure a proxy for the application to use?#

Comment: I probably could.  Is there a pass-through implementation of a proxy that could capture the timings of the http request for .net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my crude solution to the problem.  I am still looking for better solutions...

Enable System.Net logging in Web.config

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" /> 

    <sources>
        <source name="System.Net" maxdatasize="1024">
            <listeners>
                <add name="NetTimingParserListener"/>
            </listeners>
        </source>
    </sources>

    <sharedListeners>
            <add name="NetTimingParserListener" type="..." />
    </sharedListeners>

    <switches>
        <add name="System.Net" value="Verbose" />
    </switches>
</system.diagnostics>
```

The above config will enable verbose logging which I will capture with a custom trace listener.  This trace listener will parse the log files on the fly and attempt to correlate the network events & store the timings.

Next, I created an object to store the correlated events and calculate timing between them.

```
/// <summary>
/// Measure and store status and timings of a given Network request.
/// </summary>
public class RequestTrace
{
    private Stopwatch _timer = new Stopwatch();

    /// <summary>
    ///     Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Object" /> class.
    /// </summary>
    public RequestTrace(string id, Uri url)
    {
        Id = new Stack<string>();
        Id.Push(id);
        Url = url;
        IsFaulted = false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Any Id's that are associated with this request.  Such as
    /// HttpWebRequest, Connection, and associated Streams.
    /// </summary>
    public Stack<string> Id { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// The Url of the request being made.
    /// </summary>
    public Uri Url { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Time in ms for setting up the connection.
    /// </summary>
    public long ConnectionSetupTime { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Time to first downloaded byte.  Includes sending request headers,
    /// body and server processing time.
    /// </summary>
    public long WaitingTime { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Time in ms spent downloading the response.
    /// </summary>
    public long DownloadTime { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// True if the request encounters an error.
    /// </summary>
    public bool IsFaulted { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Call this method when the request begins connecting to the server.
    /// </summary>
    public void StartConnection()
    {
        _timer.Start();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Call this method when the requst successfuly connects to the server.  Otherwise, fall <see cref="Faulted"/>.
    /// </summary>
    public void StopConnection()
    {
        _timer.Stop();
        ConnectionSetupTime = _timer.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        _timer.Reset();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Call this method after connecting to the server.
    /// </summary>
    public void StartWaiting()
    {
        _timer.Start();
    }


    /// <summary>
    /// Call this method after receiving the first byte of the HTTP server
    /// response.
    /// </summary>
    public void StopWaiting()
    {
        _timer.Stop();
        WaitingTime = _timer.ElapsedMilliseconds;
        _timer.Reset();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Call this method after receiving the first byte of the HTTP reponse.
    /// </summary>
    public void StartDownloadTime()
    {
        _timer.Start();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Call this method after the response is completely received.
    /// </summary>
    public void StopDownloadTime()
    {
        _timer.Stop();
        DownloadTime = _timer.ElapsedMilliseconds;

        _timer = null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Call this method if an Exception occurs.
    /// </summary>
    public void Faulted()
    {
        DownloadTime = 0;
        WaitingTime = 0;
        ConnectionSetupTime = 0;
        IsFaulted = true;

        if (_timer.IsRunning)
        {
            _timer.Stop();
        }
        _timer = null;
    }

    /// <summary>
    ///     Returns a string that represents the current object.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    ///     A string that represents the current object.
    /// </returns>
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return IsFaulted
            ? String.Format("Request to node `{0}` - Exception", Url.DnsSafeHost)
            : String.Format("Request to node `{0}` - Connect: {1}ms - Wait: {2}ms - Download: {3}ms", Url.DnsSafeHost,
                ConnectionSetupTime, WaitingTime, DownloadTime);
    }
}
```

System.Net does not really have a single ID that correlates to the same request.  You could use the thread ID but that will break down quickly, so I needed to keep track of many different objects (HttpWebRequest, Connection, ConnectStream, etc.) and follow as they get associated with each other in the log.  I do not know of any built-in .NET types that allow you to have multiple keys mapped to a single value, so I created this crude collection for my purposes.

```
/// <summary>
/// Specialized collection that associates multiple keys with a single item.
/// 
/// WARNING: Not production quality because it does not react well to dupliate or missing keys.
/// </summary>
public class RequestTraceCollection
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Internal dictionary for doing lookups.
    /// </summary>
    private readonly Dictionary<string, RequestTrace> _dictionary = new Dictionary<string, RequestTrace>();

    /// <summary>
    /// Retrieve an item by <paramref name="key"/>.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="key">Any of the keys associated with an item</param>
    public RequestTrace this[string key]
    {
        get { return _dictionary[key]; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add an <paramref name="item"/> to the collection.  The item must
    /// have at least one string in the Id array.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">A RequestTrace object.</param>
    public void Add(RequestTrace item)
    {
        _dictionary.Add(item.Id.Peek(), item);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Given an <paramref name="item"/> in the collection, add another key
    /// that it can be looked up by.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">Item that exists in the collection</param>
    /// <param name="key">New key alias</param>
    public void AddAliasKey(RequestTrace item, string key)
    {
        item.Id.Push(key);
        _dictionary.Add(key, item);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Remove an <paramref name="item"/> from the collection along with any
    /// of its key aliases.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="item">Item to be removed</param>
    public void Remove(RequestTrace item)
    {
        while (item.Id.Count > 0)
        {
            var key = item.Id.Pop();
            _dictionary.Remove(key);
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, it was a matter of creating the custom TraceListener and parsing the logged messages.

```
public class HttpWebRequestTraceListener : TraceListener
{
    private readonly RequestTraceCollection _activeTraces = new RequestTraceCollection();

    private readonly Regex _associatedConnection =
        new Regex(@"^\[\d+\] Associating (Connection#\d+) with (HttpWebRequest#\d+)",
            RegexOptions.Compiled & RegexOptions.IgnoreCase & RegexOptions.Singleline);

    private readonly Regex _connected = new Regex(@"^\[\d+\] (ConnectStream#\d+) - Sending headers",
        RegexOptions.Compiled & RegexOptions.IgnoreCase & RegexOptions.Singleline);

    private readonly Regex _newRequest =
        new Regex(@"^\[\d+\] (HttpWebRequest#\d+)::HttpWebRequest\(([http|https].+)\)",
            RegexOptions.Compiled & RegexOptions.IgnoreCase & RegexOptions.Singleline);

    private readonly Regex _requestException = new Regex(@"^\[\d+\] Exception in (HttpWebRequestm#\d+)::",
        RegexOptions.Compiled & RegexOptions.IgnoreCase & RegexOptions.Singleline);

    private readonly Regex _responseAssociated =
        new Regex(@"^\[\d+\] Associating (HttpWebRequest#\d+) with (ConnectStream#\d+)",
            RegexOptions.Compiled & RegexOptions.IgnoreCase & RegexOptions.Singleline);

    private readonly Regex _responseComplete = new Regex(@"^\[\d+\] Exiting (ConnectStream#\d+)::Close\(\)",
        RegexOptions.Compiled & RegexOptions.IgnoreCase & RegexOptions.Singleline);

    private readonly Regex _responseStarted = new Regex(@"^\[\d+\] (Connection#\d+) - Received status line: (.*)",
        RegexOptions.Compiled & RegexOptions.IgnoreCase & RegexOptions.Singleline);

    /// <summary>
    ///     When overridden in a derived class, writes the specified
    ///     <paramref name="message" /> to the listener you create in the derived
    ///     class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">A message to write.</param>
    public override void Write(string message)
    {
        // Do nothing here
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Parse the message being logged by System.Net and store relevant event information.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="message">A message to write.</param>
    public override void WriteLine(string message)
    {
        var newRequestMatch = _newRequest.Match(message);
        if (newRequestMatch.Success)
        {
            var requestTrace = new RequestTrace(newRequestMatch.Groups[1].Value,
                new Uri(newRequestMatch.Groups[2].Value));
            requestTrace.StartConnection();

            _activeTraces.Add(requestTrace);

            return;
        }

        var associatedConnectionMatch = _associatedConnection.Match(message);
        if (associatedConnectionMatch.Success)
        {
            var requestTrace = _activeTraces[associatedConnectionMatch.Groups[2].Value];
            _activeTraces.AddAliasKey(requestTrace, associatedConnectionMatch.Groups[1].Value);

            return;
        }

        var connectedMatch = _connected.Match(message);
        if (connectedMatch.Success)
        {
            var requestTrace = _activeTraces[connectedMatch.Groups[1].Value];
            requestTrace.StopConnection();
            requestTrace.StartWaiting();

            return;
        }

        var responseStartedMatch = _responseStarted.Match(message);
        if (responseStartedMatch.Success)
        {
            var requestTrace = _activeTraces[responseStartedMatch.Groups[1].Value];
            requestTrace.StopWaiting();
            requestTrace.StartDownloadTime();

            return;
        }

        var responseAssociatedMatch = _responseAssociated.Match(message);
        if (responseAssociatedMatch.Success)
        {
            var requestTrace = _activeTraces[responseAssociatedMatch.Groups[1].Value];

            _activeTraces.AddAliasKey(requestTrace, responseAssociatedMatch.Groups[2].Value);

            return;
        }

        var responseCompleteMatch = _responseComplete.Match(message);
        if (responseCompleteMatch.Success)
        {
            var requestTrace = _activeTraces[responseCompleteMatch.Groups[1].Value];
            requestTrace.StopDownloadTime();

            _activeTraces.Remove(requestTrace);

            // TODO: At this point the request is done, use this time to store & forward this log entry
            Debug.WriteLine(requestTrace);

            return;
        }

        var faultedMatch = _requestException.Match(message);
        if (faultedMatch.Success)
        {
            var requestTrace = _activeTraces[responseCompleteMatch.Groups[1].Value];
            requestTrace.Faulted();

            _activeTraces.Remove(requestTrace);

            // TODO: At this point the request is done, use this time to store & forward this log entry
            Debug.WriteLine(requestTrace);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe what you are looking for is an action filter, you can see an example of it on the official asp.net site at:

http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs

Comment: That won't work in my use case.  I want to profile one or more WebRequests that I am making from my WebAPI not measure the performance of the overall action.

Comment: I think there are other options for monitoring the request through the http handlers and injecting that into your web.config so that it properly intercepts every request. But I don't think that is the route you would want to go either. 

I have used tools like NewRelic or some of the other DevOps type tools that will give you great insight into this information and probably some things that you didn't think about.